# jacoco's prepare-agent not generating jacoco.exec file

Tags: maven, jacoco

I am running Jacoco's Maven plugin. The `prepare-agent` goal runs fine, but does not generate `jacoco.exec` file for some reason. Subsequently the `report` goal complains `Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Having read https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/LzmCezW8VKA, it turns out that `prepare-agent` sets a surefire property called `argLine`. If you override this property (something that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-951 encourages you to do) then jacoco never ends up running.

The solution is to replace:

```
<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
```

with

```
<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding} ${argLine}</argLine>
```

Meaning, append jacoco's `argLine` to the new value.

**UPDATE**: As pointed out by [Fodder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3887715/fodder), if you aren't always running JaCoCo and no other plugin sets `${argLine}` then Maven will complain that `${argLine}` is undefined. To resolve this, simply define what `${argLine}` should look like when JaCoCo is skipped:

```
<properties>
    <argLine/>
</properties>
```

In this case use @{argLine} instead of ${argLine} as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28695766/16206).

Comment: I would add that it's needed only if you change argLine configuration for surefire plugin. Otherwise default configuration is OK.

Comment: If you are using Tycho (for Eclipse plugins and applications), use ${tycho.testArgLine} instead of ${argLine}.

Comment: Man, youre a lifesaver. Spent whole day fighting with jacoco - it couldnt generate exec file and surefire has no special arguments. Adding <argLine/> makes everything work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't always running JaCoCo when building then @Gili's solution doesn't work, as it can't find `argLine`. Instead add a property `argLine` in you POM with the custom values. JaCoCo's prepare agent will append to that property, and Surefire will use the appended argLine.

```
<properties>
    <argLine>whatever your custom argline variables are</argLine>
</properties>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- Don't put argLine config here! -->
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. You need special handling if JaCoCo is disabled but I handled it differently. I've updated my answer accordingly.