# Cannot use jacoco JVM args and surefire JVM args together in maven

Tags: maven, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using maven with the *jacoco* plugin to generate code coverage metrics. I am having some difficulty in configuring the *surefire* plugin with the java options required by the *jacoco* plugin. I've seen some answers about this already on Stack Overflow but something is not working for me.

I have a multi-module project, and one of my modules configures the *surefire* plugin as follows:

`foo/pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This works as expected.

Now I want to incorporate jacoco to get code coverage metrics, so I added a *CodeCoverage* profile that handles all the jacoco configuration:

`parent/pom.xml`:

```
<profile>
  <id>CodeCoverage</id>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
              <goals><goal>prepare-agent</goal></goals>
              <configuration>
                <propertyName>surefire.argLine</propertyName>
              </configuration>
              ...
            </execution>
          <executions> 
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>   
</profile>
```

It is seen here that if the *CodeCoverage* profile is specified, then the *jacoco* plugin is configured to use the `surefire.argLine` property, and that property is used to configure the `argLine` for the *surefire* plugin.

I then updated the *pom.xml* file for the *foo* module to use the `surefire.argLine` property generated by the *jacoco* plugin:

`foo/pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>${surefire.argLine} -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This approach is specified in the *jacoco* plugin documentation (see [1]).

When I build the *foo* module with the *CodeCoverage* profile, I see the following:

```
[foo] $ mvn clean install -X -PCodeCoverage
...
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.0.201403182114:prepare-agent (jacoco-initialize) @ foo ---
[INFO] surefire.argLine set to -javaagent:...\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.0.201403182114\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.0.201403182114-runtime.jar=destfile=...\foo\\\target\\coverage-reports\\jacoco-ut.exec
...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) argLine = -javaagent:...\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.0.201403182114\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.0.201403182114-runtime.jar=destfile=...\\foo\\target\\coverage-reports\\jacoco-ut.exec -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
...
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.0.201403182114:report (jacoco-site) @ foo ---
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'Foo' with 59 classes`
```

So the *jacoco* plugin is executed, a `surefire.argLine` property is created, the `argLine` for the *surefire* plugin uses the `surefire.argLine` property and the local `MaxPermSize` argument, and a `target\code-coverage\jacoc-ut-exec` file is generated, as expected.

However, if I do not use the *CodeCoverage* profile, then I get an error, because the `${surefire.argLine}` property (used in `foo/pom.xml`) is not created by the *jacoco* plugin, and is not defined anywhere:

```
[foo] $ mvn clean install -X
...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) argLine = ${surefire.argLine} -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
...
Error: Could not find or load main class ${surefire.argLine}`
```

Sinec the *jacoco* plugin was not invoked, there's no `surefire.argLine` property created, hence the error.

So, I go back to the `parent/pom.xml` and create this property, with no initial value:

`parent/pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <surefire.argLine></surefire.argLine>
</properties>
```

Now when I build the *foo* module without using the *CodeCoverage* profile, I get no errors:

```
[foo] $ mvn clean install -X
...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) argLine =  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS`
```

The *surefire* argline is now correct (using the empty `surefire.argLine` property) and there is no `target\code-coverage` directory, as expected.

So now I go back to generating code metrics, using the *CodeCoverage* profile:

```
[foo] $ mvn clean install -X -PCodeCoverage
...
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.0.201403182114:prepare-agent (jacoco-initialize) @ foo ---
[INFO] surefire.argLine set to -javaagent:...\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.0.201403182114\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.0.201403182114-runtime.jar=destfile=...\\foo\\target\\coverage-reports\\jacoco-ut.exec
...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) argLine =  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
...
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.0.201403182114:report (jacoco-site) @ foo ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:...\foo\target\coverage-reports\jacoco-ut.exec
```

It can be observed here that the *jacoco* plugin is invoked and sets the `surefire.argLine` property, but the `surefire.argLine` property with the empty value defined in the `parent/pom.xml` file is actually used to create the argline for the *surefire* plugin.

As a result, there is no `jacoco-ut.exec` file, and no `target\code-coverage` directory, when I use the *CodeCoverage* profile.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I'm declaring an `argLine` property as suggested by the *jacoco* documentation, and using it whenever a *surefire* plugin needs to specify additional argument. Other answers on Stack Overflow suggest creating a property with the same name as the *jacoco* argLine property to handle the case when *jacoco* is not invoked.

Any suggestions?

**edit**

Maybe one solution is to explicitly declare the `surefire.argLine` property in the *CodeCoverage* profile, and forget about using the `argLine` of the *jacoco* plugin:

```
<profile>
  <id>CodeCoverage</id>
  <properties>
    <surefire.argLine>-javaagent:${jacoco.agent.jar}=destfile=${jacoco.report.path}</surefire.argLine>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <!-- no longer specifying 'argLine' for jacoco plugin ... -->  
          </execution>
        <executions> 
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- ... instead the arg line is configured explicitly for surefire plugin. -->
          <argLine>${surefire.argLine}</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

This will create the *surefire.argLine* property to use the java agent required by the *jacoco* plugin, and configure the *surefire* plugin to use that property for its JVM args. The *jacoco* plugin will now create a *argLine* property, but this will be ignored. It's not an elegant solution (since I'm making assumptions about how the *jacoco* plugin works, and this may change in a future version).

**edit**

The `jacoco.agent.jar` property must also be set, by pointing to its location in the local repository (not sure if this is robust) or by using the *dependency* plugin to copy the *jacoco* agent jar to the local build directory:

```
<profile>
  <id>CodeCoverage</id>
  <properties>
    <jacoco.agent.jar>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-agent.jar</jacoco.agent.jar>
    ...
  </project>
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>download-jacoco-agent</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                  <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
                  <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                  <classifier>runtime</classifier>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>jacoco-agent.jar</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

**edit**

Not sure if using the *dependency* plugin is the right approach, or pointing to the jacoco agent artifact in the local repository:

```
<profile>
  <id>CodeCoverage</id>
  <properties>
    <jacoco.agent.jar>${settings.localRepository}/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/${jacoco.version}/org.jacoco.agent-${jacoco.version}-runtime.jar</jacoco.agent.jar>
  </properties>
  ...
</profile>
```

This is simpler, and does not require copying an artifact to the local build directory, but is fragile: changes in the repository layout will break this.

[1] http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269558/maven-jacoco-plugin-error

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since the `jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent` goal executes before the maven-surefire-plugin, try adding the `${argLine}` variable into the `argLine` value set by the maven-surefire-plugin.

Example:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-server -ea -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx4g -XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${argLine}</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I had the same problem and this solution worked for me, without any need to reconfigure other sections of the POM.

Answer (score 61):

Try using

```
@{argLine}
```

instead of

```
${argLine}
```

(or `surefire.argLine` in your case)

It allows surefire to read a property as modified by other plugins instead of reading the one substituted by Maven itself. Then you can set the `argLine` param to empty in Maven properties:

```
<properties>
    <argLine></argLine>
</properties>
```

Which now will not cause any problems. More here: [How do I use properties set by other plugins in argLine?](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#late-property-evaluation)

Comment: This works really well for me, but unfortunately some IDEs (namely IntellJ up to 14.1.4) seem to have a problem with that -- for example as reported in http://stackoverflow.com/q/24115142/3281722

Comment: IntelliJ users can find solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115142/intellij-error-when-running-unit-test-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-suref/35378564#35378564)

Comment: Intellij version 2017.2 has no issues with this and for me was far simpler a fix than the one further up.

Comment: Where is the `@` syntax documented? I've used `${argLine}` with a default value in `<properties>` in the past and it worked just fine. Why would I need `@{argLine}`?

Comment: @Gili Per [the `maven-surefire-plugin` FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html) linked in the answer: "Maven does property replacement for `${...}` values in `pom.xml` before any plugin is run. So Surefire would never see the place-holders in its `argLine` property.
Since the Version 2.17 using an alternate syntax for these properties, `@{...}` allows late replacement of properties when the plugin is executed, so properties that have been modified by other plugins will be picked up correctly."

Comment: @Kaszaq you are my hero... that @ instead of $ was exactly the deferred property evaluation I was looking for!!! Thanks a million...7 years later your comment is paying off! :)

Answer (score 22):

If your project already uses the argLine to configure the surefire-maven-plugin, **be sure that argLine defined as a property, rather than as part of the plugin configuration**. For example:

```
  <properties>
    <argLine>-your -extra -arguments</argLine>
  </properties>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <!-- Do not define argLine here! -->
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Resulting coverage information is collected during execution and by default written to a file when the process terminates.

Worked for me. See: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

Comment: This worked for me after all other solutions above on this page failed!

Answer (score 13):

Try adding the argLine property in the properties section (as shown in the code below) instead of adding it in the configuration section of maven-sure-fire plugin. Jacoco maven plugin will just append to this and things will work as expected.

```
<properties>
  <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
</properties>
```

See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin

Comment: This has the same effect as not including ${argLine} in the first place, makind jacoco not produce output

Comment: This worked for me. Documentation: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

Comment: That page doesn't exist anymore, the new one says: Deprecated since Java Plugin version 2.4 embedding directly the support of JaCoCo.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is to use multiple profiles.

The first profile sets a blank value for the `surefire.argLine` and the `failsafe.argLine` and is active by default.

```
<profile>
    <id>not-sonar</id>
    <properties>
        <surefire.argLine/>
        <failsafe.argLine/>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

The second profile has the jacoco plugin configuration and is inactive by default.

```
<profile>
<id>sonar</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>surefire.argLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>failsafe.argLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</profile>
```

When you activate the sonar profile the not-sonar profile will automatically be turned off.

This should be a little more elegant than using other plugins to do the work for you.  You can now use the `${surefire.argLine}` variable in your argLine and it will always exists and be set when you run your build.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>${surefire.argLine} -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

If you still have problems because the ${surefire.argLine} does not have a value you can also set a dummy property like so:

```
<profile>
    <id>not-sonar</id>
    <properties>
        <surefire.argLine>-DdummyProperty=notUsed</surefire.argLine>
        <failsafe.argLine>-DdummyProperty=notUsed</failsafe.argLine>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into the same issue and even took implicitly the same steps as you described with the same result. No clean solution I found worked for me.

So I ran several steps in debug mode and it seems that Maven replaces properties twice. That is not just in a lazy manner, as I thought, but in both eager and lazy manner:

1. **eagerly** (before any goal is run) are replaced **static** properties (defined in `properties` section of POM and probably also settings.xml),
2. **lazily** (before each execution) are replaced **dynamic** properties.

This is where our step with setting a blank property as a default failed. Maven just went:

1. eager replace of default value (blank)
2. JaCoCo sets dynamic value
3. lazy replace of dynamic values (nothing to replace now, already used the blank value)

Finally the solution is to set the default value dynamically. This can be done with GMaven plugin like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>set-default-values</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>
          project.properties.'surefire.argLine' = ''
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

So now Maven goes:

1. eager replace of static properties
2. GMaven dynamically sets default value (if profile is active)
3. JaCoCo sets dynamic value
4. Surefire runs with correctly set argLine

With active profile the exec file is generated, with non-active profile the blank default value is used and build succeeds.

Comment: Interesting solution. I will need to try this out.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to use argLine in the maven-surefire-plugin safely.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>set-custom-arg-line</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    def argLine = project.properties['argLine'];
                    if (argLine == null) {
                        argLine = "";
                    }
                    project.properties.argLine = argLine;
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m ${argLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me upgrading the version from 0.7.7.201606060606 to 0.7.9 also fixed this.

I had to explicitly add the version to the commandline (not just to the pom) because the build server kept using the old verison. This can be done as follows:

```
 org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent
```

instead of

```
org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent
```

The [jacoco plugin site (for sonar)](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin) states that argline must be added as a property. For me it also worken when using the `@{argLine}` in the surefire plugin settings.

Answer (score 1):

Update the POM.xml as

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.1</version>
      <configuration>
         <argLine>${argLine} -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1048m</argLine> 
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and then the most important thing is to run the Maven project with goals:
**mvn jacoco:prepare-agent clean test jacoco:report**

Answer (score 0):

I have added a [Maven/Java project](https://github.com/johan974/spring_unittest_or_integrationtest_findbugs_jacoco) with 1 domain class with the following features:

- **Unit or Integration testing** with the plugins Surefire and Failsafe.
- Findbugs.
- Test coverage via **Jacoco**.

I kept the project as simple as possible. The project puts many suggestions from these and other posts together in an example project. Thank you, contributors!

The readme file gives a brief explanation. It explains how you can run either a user or an integration test with **Jacoco**.

Enjoy!

Comment: What does this project help here? It does not work at 2019-06