# IntelliJ Error when running unit test: Could not find or load main class ${surefireArgLine}

Tags: junit, intellij-idea, maven-surefire-plugin

I get the following error when running Unit tests in IntelliJ:
Error: Could not find or load main class ${surefireArgLine}.
I am using maven and in pom.xml I have:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <surefire.argLine />
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
             <!--Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run.-->
            <argLine>${surefire.argLine}</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
            <executions>
                <!--
                    Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data.-->
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        <!--
                            Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                            for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                        -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
   ...
```

Did anyone have similiar problem? How to set value for surefireArgLine?

Answer (score 324, accepted):

I had the same problem and i think i found the solution on the [vertx-issue tracker](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-ext-parent/issues/7).

In short you have to configure your IntelliJ Maven (surefire plugin) integration to behave differently.

This works for me in IntelliJ 14.1.6 with mvn 3.3.9
`Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Running Tests`

For IntelliJ 2019 and above
`Settings-> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Running Tests`

Uncheck `argLine`

Comment: Thanks its the same problem here in start of 2016 ;)

Comment: In Intellij 2016: `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Maven` -> `Running Tests`

Comment: Same problem, but sans surefire. Getting error "Could not find or load main class ${argLine}". This works.

Comment: Thank you...what are the chances of finding such a post when trying to make changes to a build and making sure it does not have side effects for the developers...god bless stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi from 2018 :) This is a precious piece of solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: In Intellij 2018: `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Running Tests`

Comment: Similar problem for me with error message containing @{argLine}. Resolution works.

Comment: problem still happening, unchecking `argLine` fixed for me

Comment: That feeling when you realize it's not the first time you're reading an answer. I was going to upvote it but then I saw it was already upvoted by me :-)

Comment: Seems we can upvote for issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145991 .

Comment: April 2021, still a valid answer.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to fix this error in Netbeans by changing the surefire-plugin version to 2.10 and removing

```
<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ${argLine}</argLine>
```

from the maven-surefire-plugin configuration. Instead i have created a property argLine that is picked automatically by surefire.

```
<properties>
    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
  </properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
      </plugin>
```

Now, i can run and debug single files and test methods. And Code Coverage is working as expected.

Comment: This works for IntelliJ too.  This option is [mentioned in the JaCoCo documentation](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html).

Answer (score 4):

Update of pom.xml solved my problem.

```
<argLine>${surefire.argLine}</argLine>
```

Complete plugin info in pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>    
            <version>2.18.1</version>                 
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>   
                <jvm>${env.JDK1_8_HOME}\bin\java</jvm>   
                <argLine>${surefire.argLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
     </plugin> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for this and found this project "fix" it in this [thread](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1196)

Basically define your jacocoArgLine var name as empty project property. Then in surefire configuration use @{jacocoArgLine} instead of dollar prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have to run my test case from maven with 
    mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test
not directly from IDE.

Comment: Did you ever found another sollution for this? I need to run it from my IDE to be able to use debug mode.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I haven't found another solution for this.

Comment: @LisaMM you can debug tests without running the tests in an IDE. Just start the tests with *mvnDebug* on the command line. Then use your favorite IDE to connect to the command line process. Google for "remote debug" in your favorite IDE.

Comment: @BlueLettuce16 solution proposed by "jah" (has 200+ ups) is much better, could you please mark accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

For a more permanent fix for every new project add the following to your IntelliJ IDEA Custom VM Options:

1. Help > Edit Custom VM options
2. Add: `-Didea.maven.surefire.disable.argLine=true`

This will deactivate surefire for all new projects you open.