# configure Jacoco for Integration test code coverage

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to configure Jacoco agent for code coverage but it's not generating any coverage. This is my current configuration:

I have 2 projects lets call them project A & project B. Project A is where I want to generate coverage report for. Its running on wildfly and I configured Jacoco Agent as vm argument like this:

***-javaagent:/jacocoagent.jar=port=36320,destfile=jacoco-it.exec,output=tcpserver***

Project B is a maven project from where I am executing the test cases.I configured the jacoco maven plugin like this:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-report</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>${skip.int.tests.report}</skip>
              <target>
                <!-- Execute an ant task within maven -->
                <echo message="Generating JaCoCo Reports"/>
                <taskdef name="report" classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask">
                  <classpath path="${basedir}/target/jacoco-jars/org.jacoco.ant.jar"/>
                </taskdef>
                <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/coverage-report"/>
                <report>
                  <executiondata>
                    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                      <include name="target/jacoco-it*.exec"/>
                    </fileset>
                  </executiondata>
                  <structure name="jacoco-multi Coverage Project">
                    <group name="jacoco-multi">
                      <classfiles>
                        <fileset dir="target/classes"/>
                      </classfiles>
                      <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                        <fileset dir="src"/>
                      </sourcefiles>
                    </group>
                  </structure>
                  <html destdir="${basedir}/target/coverage-report/html"/>
                  <xml destfile="${basedir}/target/coverage-report/coverage-report.xml"/>
                  <csv destfile="${basedir}/target/coverage-report/coverage-report.csv"/>
                </report>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

I configured the maven surefire plugin like this:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
           <!--    Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                <environmentVariables>
                <BLUEOPTIMA_HOME>${project.basedir}/</BLUEOPTIMA_HOME>
                </environmentVariables>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <BLUEOPTIMA_HOME>${project.basedir}</BLUEOPTIMA_HOME>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <!--<suiteXmlFile>suites-test-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I execute the mvn test command its not generating any code coverage reports. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your jacoco configuration looks abnormally complicated. Have you looked at this very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304793/jacoco-with-maven-missing-execution-data-file) and that [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395255/maven-jacoco-not-generating-code-coverage-report) too ?

Comment: yeah I looked at the similar configurations and I followed this blog to configure Jacoco plugin:  https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

> When I execute the mvn test command

In your configuration goal `run` of `maven-antrun-plugin` is bound to `post-integration-test` phase, which is after `test` phase and hence not executed by command `mvn test` - see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html